# Filtros excelphp

Tags: php, base-de-datos, cakephp, phpexcel

Hola estoy usando esta libreria 
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

y quiero agregar un filtro de fecha y hora que quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la BD la info esta en la sgt estructura: `2018-06-19 12:13:21` pero al meterlo en la celda lo lee como texto y no como fecha

que he intentado?

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('I'.$i, $user->created);
$this->longitudCeldas('I', $user->created,  $worksheet);

$worksheet->getCell('I'.$i)->setValueExplicit("'".$user->created."'",\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Si agrego la linea anterior lo lee como numero, por lo cual pienso que la solución esta por este lado.

```
$worksheet->getStyle('I'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno ya encontré la solución para que el archivo de excel filtre automaticamente como una fecha:

```
 $worksheet->setCellValue('I'.$i, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExcel($user->created));
```

En la linea anterior convierto la fecha obtenida(`$user->created`) de la base de datos en el formato valido para excel, y luego le doy un formato a la celda que es como el cliente vera la fecha

```
$worksheet->getStyle('I'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('yyyy/mm/dd  [$-240A]hh:mm:ss am/pm');
```

Entonces `yyyy/mm/dd` equivale a el año con 4 dígitos, el mes en formato numérico con 2 dígitos, el día en formato numérico con dos dígitos y todo separado por `/`, `[$-240A]hh:mm:ss am/pm` equivale a que es un formato de 12 horas así que si en la base de datos esta configurado como formato de 24 horas esto lo convierte diferenciando el día y la noche con `am/pm`, y las horas, minutos y segundos los pone de 2 dígitos y separados por `:`

Y con esto el filtro queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad, ya que las respuestas que son solo codigo son consideradas malas. Por favor, mira [answer] y explica un poco mejor sobre el problema y la solucion

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/106060)

Comment: @gbianchi ya explique mejor la pregunta.

Comment: @fedorqui ya organice mi respuesta